# Does the default Wordpress video player support closed captions?

Tags: video-player

We want to used closed captions on a video so people can turn them on/off in the player like you do in Youtube. We aren't hosting this particular video on Youtube; it will just be uploaded to the site and embedded by pasting in the video url.

Comment: It supposed to, at least it has a corresponding interface for adding captions tracks in VTT format to the video media element via the classic editor (default Gutenberg video block does not have such an interface), but when I tried to use it, I can't manage to get it working.

Comment: My question was about embedding videos in the classic editor but the video block in Wordpress 5.6 now allows you to upload video captions directly in the block editor.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Wordpress has its own video player, but HTML5 video player supports closed captions.

This is the example.

```
<video  width="320" height="240">  
 
     <source type="video/mp4" src="/my_video_file.mp4" >   
     <track src="/captions_file.vtt" label="English" kind="captions" srclang="en-us" default >
     <track src="/French_captions_file.vtt" label="French" kind="subtitles" srclang="fr" >

</video>
```

But, I recommend this [Video.js](https://videojs.com/)